# How to avoid lag while expanding a custom ListViewItem in Windows Phone 8.1?

Tags: xaml, listview, windows-phone-8.1, transition, lag

I've created a ListView with custom ListViewItems which will expand if you click/tap on them. This works with two different ContentTemplates. One for the standard item and one for the expanded.

If there are about 5 items in the ListView, the *RepositionThemeTransition* I'm using on the ListView stutters while expanding an item. I already found out the problem, but I can't solve it.
The custom ListViewItem's content gets arranged in a Grid and the 2nd column uses StarSizing. If I use a fixed value like 300 px there is no lag and everything works as expected. But with the lag the ListView seems to get a smaller width while expanding and then again the original width after the transition.

```
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
     <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
     <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
     <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
     <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
     <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
</Grid.RowDefinitions>
```

Comment: Dynamic sized will call a lot of calculation within the animations. You could try to put some timers the Measure and Arrange overrides to get some insights. Other idea would be to use a usercontrol instead of two templates and animate the change with two visual states. Could run better than the RepositionTransition.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. After a few hours of testing I actually found a work-around. I'm not sure if it's a bug or something, but if you set the MinWidth of the main grid to sth like 200px, then there's no lag. It's like the control resizes itself to a smaller width and then realizes it was wrong and becomes larger again :D The MinWidth property restricts this behaviour.